# What are the downsides of using text-shadow for font anti-aliasing?

Tags: css

I found this method:

```
.fontSmooth { text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(51,51,51,0.5); }
```

and it works perfectly! but in some places it is said that it's a bad solution (with no further explanation), why is that?

Comment: I don't think you'll stumble upon any problem with any modern browser, except the eternal bug in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23440

Comment: @Ilya Text-shadow renders differently, it doesn't look the same in different browsers. To see the difference, try a large font-size and a larger text-shadow...

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense when you consider that **`text-shadow` was never *intended* for use for anti-aliasing in the first place**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll probably *work*, though there are two main issues.

First off, as [coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward) originally pointed out (though he apparently deleted the post after one downvote), the `text-shadow` property is part of an ever-changing HTML5 spec. It's relatively new on the scene, and its syntax and implementation are liable to be extremely different across browsers and may change even further over the next few years.

The more short-term issue here, though, is that blurring a text shadow takes serious work on the part of the browser. It's fine for maybe headers and the like, but if you're planning to apply this to your whole page, please bear in mind that it will run much slower in older computers, and even scrolling up and down will be laggy. So, be careful in deciding to what extent such smoothing is appropriate.

I'd also like to point out that, if the user hasn't enabled anti-aliasing system-wide, it's quite possible that the user doesn't want it. It's just kinda silly to use CSS tricks to override a platform-level setting.

Comment: thanx, since it seems that fonts simply look ugly on windows, are there better ways to smooth them out? The big headers are the main issue - the bigger they are the uglier they become...

Comment: @IlyaD: anti-aliasing is a setting on Windows. [Maybe ClearType isn't enabled?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306527) There really isn't really a *good* way to control this as a web designer :/

Comment: Or just get everyone to use IE9, fonts look brilliant in it, plus it ignores `text-shadow` so you don't have to use it as a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not try to fix that kind of things that are responsibility of users-side. It might work well under certain conditions, but as shadows were not meant for that, you cannot be sure its visual impact on different conditions.